# understanding module.exports with callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, asynccallback

I have a situation where I am creating a node module that returns only when an asynchronous operation is completed.  One way to do this (shown below), is to assign module.exports a function with a callback parameter.  Inside the function, you would then return the callback.

Here's an example of what I describe, with done being callback:

```
// module called test.js
module.exports = function(done) {
  // do something asynchronous here
  process.nextTick(function() {
    done();  //  call done when the asynchronous thing is complete...
  }
}
```

Where I am getting hung up, is in how the callback done is indeed being executed, considering I don't define it anywhere...

For example, in vanilla javascript, I can pass done as parameter and then call it within the function, as long as I create the callback function in the invocation.

```
function testAsyncCb(msg, done) {
  console.log(msg);
  setTimeout( function() {
    done();
  }, 1000);
  console.log("last line in code");
}

testAsyncCb("testing", function(){ console.log("done"); });  // invocation with callback function
```

Back in the first node example, somewhere the call to module.exports by require() is creating a function for the done() to resolve to right?  If not, how is the callback resolving?

Having a hard time finding information for how this works.  Any help/direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think of **module.exports** as an object (module.exports = {}). So whatever you put to the object will be publicly visible to anyone do require module.

For instance, you have

```
 module.exports = function myFunc() {}
```

then require to that would mean

```
var abc = require('./my-module'); --> abc == myFunc
```

if you would do

```
module.export.myFunc = function () {}
```

than require would be

```
var abc = require('./my-module'); --> abc == {myFunc: function () {}}
```

require operation is sync, not async like in requirejs (meaning not AMD but more like commonjs).

see http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/
for more info
also for nodejs official docs: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Comment: I updated the question to be more clear.  Using your example, I'm still not sure where a callback get's defined when using require.  So if abc = {myFunc: function(done) { done(); }} where is that done being defined?

Comment: you do require and get back a function. than you can call that function. your function i see gets a callback, so just call it with a cb as an arg, but still, the export itself is sync and the function is defined and returned sync. how you call the function after you get it, is up to you. check the links in my original post.

Comment: got it - the key is treat the require() function like an object as you mentioned.  after parsing through some code more, I realized the module is being called with a callback as an argument as you suggest in your comment like so require('./some-module)( function( ){  });